# writing .Rmd files in Geany IDE

Tags: r, r-markdown, geany, rnotebook

I've been using Geany under Linux to write R scripts for years. Now I want to use R Notebook and R Markdown.

So, what should I do to make Geany recognize .Rmd files used by R? Is it possible?

I did not find a proper plugin or documentation for .Rmd files in Geany.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Antonio! It is possible to write R-scripts ('.R' files) with markdown sintax and then use `rmarkdown::render()` to export the report. Check this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/simpleblog/gh-pages/assets/R/renderRscript2markdown_sample.R

Comment: helped a lot, thanks Jose